# Actual Window Manager from Windows Ubuntu Unity equivalent

Tags: 16.04, unity, tiling

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get a tiling manager working the way I got the Actual Window Manager from Windows to work. I'm looking for something which will allow me to do this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hzJb.jpg

I've tried getting Awesome, compiz, i3 and similar ones to work but they all don't run in the unity interface.

Does something like this even exsist for Ubuntu Unity?

Any help would be much appreciated!